# XCode 6 Table View cell running off the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a table view cell inside of a view controller in Xcode storyboard.  The cell is formatted 'Right detail' with a Title on the left and Subtitle on the right.  It looks like the cell is too wide for the screen - and the Subtitle information has rolled off the side of the screen.  I'm on Xcode 6.  The table view looks like this

[image]

But it should look like this

[image]

Is there some formatting option I could check so that the information fits neatly in the table view screen?  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You should set constraints to tableView to position it. Just set constraints trailing space and leading space of tableView in the storyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the `resolve layout issues` tab at the bottom right, above where the debug panel goes and select `Reset to suggested constraints` with your tableview selected. If that doesn't work then you'll need to constrain the right side of your tableview to the superview manually, this can be done by control dragging (like an IB connection) from the superview to the tableview and selecting the appropriate constraint in the scene hierarchy to the left of your storyboard editor.

Comment: If you've already manually dragged the width you're going to want to reset it to fill the "screen" BEFORE following this. Otherwise it's going to be too narrow. If you do that just `clear constraints` in the same menu, resize and follow the answer as written.